# Install Ubuntu on Lenovo V330-14IKB

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

I am new to Ubuntu, recently I installed it on my desktop (Lenovo), which was previously loaded with Windows. After trying it and comparing it with the previous OS, I definitely do not want to get back to Windows. I would also like to install it on my laptop Lenovo V330-14IKB, but surfing the web I found many commentaries reporting problems with Lenovo.

Is it safe to install Ubuntu 20.04 on this laptop?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to try it. Use the Live USB, select “Try Ubuntu”, and see if everything works well enough. If it does, install. If it doesn’t, create some new questions asking about things that don’t work 

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   (other than trying various releases, even various stacks; eg. LTS releases have the GA or HWE stack so whilst one stack may suit your device, the other won't; I have an old IBM thinkpad that is great using the 18.04 GA stack but has issues with HWE once it past 5.3).   Your question is *opinion* related though and better suited for a Forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/) and not this Q&A site where it's off-topic

Comment: 18.04 stack choices; 18.04 & 18.04.1 media use the GA stack, ie. 4.15 kernel, 18.04.2 used the 4.18 kernel & stack, 18.04.3 used 5.0, 18.04.4 used 5.3, and 18.04.5 used the final 5.4 kernel (GA kernel for 20.04), so be aware Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two options (GA  & HWE)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack